# How to write function assigning nested object to parent object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I want to write an `equipWeapon` function runs, when an HTML image is clicked, which reassigns the `weapon` property of the object to the first element of the `inventory` array.

HTML:

```
<img src="bag.png" id="bag" onclick="equipWeapon()">
```

JS:

```
const player1= { 
  name: "Bob",
  inventory: [ { type: 'mace', damage: 5 } ],
  health: 10,
  weapon: { 
      type: 'baseball bat',
      damage: 2
       }
};

function equipWeapon2(h) {
    if (h.inventory.length > 0) {
        h.weapon= h.inventory[0]
    } else {

    }
}

function equipWeapon() {
    equipWeapon2(player1);
}
```

Comment: what error/problem are you facing?

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52915352/edit) then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] using placeholder.com for example for your images

Answer (score 0):

This function will switch the current player's weapon property with the weapon in position 0 at the inventory array.

```
function equipWeapon2(h) {
    if (h.inventory.length > 0) {
        let oldWeapon = h.weapon;
        h.weapon= h.inventory[0]
        h.inventory[0] = oldWeapon;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.